# Find count of missing elements in an unsorted array of integers

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, performance

How can I find how many elements are missing from an array of integers in C, if some of the numbers are duplicated?

Assume the array is `int array = {1, 2, 1, 5, 4}` and there should be numbers up to `6`. Then, the program/function should output/return `2`, as there are 2 elements missing (`3, 6`).

Note: 0 is not counted as a missing number, nor can it be present in an array.

Comment: Are you saying an array of length `n` can have numbers between `1` to `n+1`?

Comment: @YoungHobbit No, the array elements could've been the same, but for example numbers up to 10 could have been missing. Therefore, there would be 6 elements missing. The maximum number of the sequence (6 in the question) can be anything. (But it is obviously specified beforehand)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way?

```
int countMissing(int *x, int arrLen, int bound)
{
  int * y = malloc ((bound + 1) * sizeof(int));
  int i  = 0;
  int missing = 0;
  memset(y,0,sizeof(int)*(bound+1));


  for(i = 0; i<arrLen; i++)
  {
    if(x[i]<=bound)
    {
      y[x[i]] = 1;
    }else
    {
       // error handling e.g.
       return -1;
    }

  }

  for(i = 1; i<=bound; i++)
  {
    if(y[i]==0) missing++;
  }

  free(y);
  return missing;
}
```

Usage:

```
int main(void) 
{
   int array [] = {1, 2, 1, 5, 4};
   printf("%d", countMissing(array, 5, 10));
   return 0;
}
```

Output: 6.

Comment: Nits: (1) you should allocate `char *y` to save some space; (2) you should use `y[x[i]-1]` or allocate an array of size `bound+1`, because otherwise you have an out-of-bounds access; (3) you should free your array.

Comment: @nneonneo:  fixing, I don't have a debugger with me; should work now

Comment: Why are you using `memset()` instead of `calloc()`?

Comment: @Mitsos101: That is a style thing

Comment: @Giorgi Does the memory need to be zeroed out anyway though?

Comment: @Mitsos101:malloc doesn't initialize memory, you need to initialize it to some values, otherwise reading it will be undefined behaviour

Comment: Weird, using the previous code (without zeroing out the memory) works too.

Comment: @Mitsos101: if it happens some element of array is not initialized and you read it you get undefined behaviour - which is bad. That said if you have undefined behaviour anything might happen, and you may get any result

Comment: `calloc` is a wrapper for `malloc` and `memset(ptr,'\0',size);`

Comment: The final scan over `y` can easily be eliminated.

Comment: @rici:what do you mean?

Comment: If You check bounds, do both sides -> x[i]>=0. And as mentioned, You basically need array of booleans, array of integers wastes 31x more memory than it really needs.